# No result defined for action and result

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, actionresult

Default result is not rendering using result for my package alone. Flow goes to my `n0result` method then It throws `Exception`.

Please correct my wrong configuration.

**Output :**

```
Hello How are you noresult() method got called.....
Dec 26, 2013 12:48:04 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher serviceAction
SEVERE: Could not find action or result
No result defined for action leo.struts.HelloWorldAction and result noresult - action - file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Strut2Examples/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:99:93
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:350)
```

**Form:**

```
<s:form action="noresultactionupdate" >            
            <s:submit value="noresultactionupdate"/>
</s:form>
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<package name="resultpackage" extends="struts-default">     
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="defaultdispatcher" default="true"
                class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult" />
        </result-types>

        <action name="noresultactionupdate" class="leo.struts.HelloWorldAction" method="noresult">
            <result name="success">/noresultend.jsp</result>
            <result name="defaultdispatcher">/noresultdefaultdispatcher.jsp</result>
        </action>       
</package>
```

**Action :**

```
public String noresult() throws Exception {         
    System.out.println("Hello How are you noresult() method got called.....");
    setMessage("noresult");
    return "noresult";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the struts configuration. What is wrong is that `"noresult"` result is not found in the action configuration. You have either configure a result or return a result code that you have in the action config such as `SUCCESS` for example.

```
public String noresult() throws Exception {         
    System.out.println("Hello How are you noresult() method got called.....");
    setMessage("noresult");
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I thought I can define my own result type.Thats whyconfused with this.Is this possible to create my own result type in Struts2?

Answer (score 2):

What ever the `string value` your are returning from the **action class method**. You must declare a `result name with the returned string value`. 
example in your code:

Change

`<result name="success">/noresultend.jsp</result>`

to

`<result name="noresult">/noresultend.jsp</result>`

**OR**

You can add one more result in the action. like below

```
    <action name="noresultactionupdate" 
            class="leo.struts.HelloWorldAction" method="noresult">
      <result name="success">/noresultend.jsp</result>
     <result name="noresult">/noresultend.jsp</result>
      <result name="defaultdispatcher">/noresultdefaultdispatcher.jsp</result>
      </action>
```

I hope It ll work.